# running a constructer from within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, thor, rails-generate

So I'm attempting to run a generator from within a controller
the idea being that i could generate a scaffold from within a rails application

for testing purposes ive created a small generator that creates an initializer with no real content. i've run this from within the shell (rails generate initializer)

```
lib/generators/initializer_generator.rb
    class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      def create_initializer_file
        create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
      end
    end
```

but the problem comes in when i attempt to run the generator from a controller

```
class GeneratorController < ApplicationController
  include Rails::Generators
  include Rails::Generators::Actions

  def index
    generate(:initializer)
  end

end
```

so this bring the response 'undefined method `behavior'
then i did some research knowing that rails generators are based apon Thor
and found that the behavior method is a thor method in the Thor::Actions modules
[http://rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions:behavior](http://rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions%3abehavior)

So I changed the controller code to include that module:

```
class GeneratorController < ApplicationController
    include Rails::Generators
    include Rails::Generators::Actions
    include Thor::Actions

  def index
    generate(:initializer)
  end

end
```

Now the error is 'wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)'. Am very confused now about what might be going wrong.

Comment: using backticks is a solution to this

Comment: using backticks is a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the class directly?

```
InitializerGenerator.new.initializer
```

This is an advantage of Thor over Rake, these are regular Ruby classes.

I had to set the destination_root inside my method, example:

```
  def create_initializer_file
    destination_root = Rails.root
    create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
  end
```

I've only just started using generators so there might be a better way.

One issue I ran in to after this, which I have yet to solve is that Thor prompts for user input if the file already exists.